# How to disable collapsing the open accordion group in AngularUI

Tags: accordion, angular-ui

I know I can use  close-others to make sure no more than one group is open, but I want to make sure exactly one group is open. That is, I want to prevent the user from being able to close the ope group.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not possible to do it with the accordion. What I ended up doing is replacing the accordion with a list of [collapse](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse) items that has ng-click that set the current selected item, and unselect the previously selected item.